# Upload image to Spring Server API in Android

Tags: java, android, spring

i'm traying to upload a image in Android App to my api, but i have this menssage:

"The current request is not a multipart request"

I've this code in my app android:

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {

        // url where the data will be posted
        String postReceiverUrl = "http://...";
        Log.v("TEST", "postURL: " + postReceiverUrl);

// HttpClient
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

// post header
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(postReceiverUrl);
        try {
            // the URL where the file will be posted

            File file = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
            FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file);

            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            reqEntity.addPart("file", fileBody);
            httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);

// execute HTTP post request
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

            if (resEntity != null) {

                String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();
                Log.v("TEST ", "Response: " +  responseStr);

                // you can add an if statement here and do other actions based on the response
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "";
    }
```

And in my API i've this code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file) {
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                File file1 = new File("test.jpg");
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file1);
                BufferedOutputStream stream =
                        new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                stream.write(bytes);
                stream.close();
                System.out.println("The path is: ");
                System.out.println(file1.getAbsolutePath());
                System.out.println(file1.getPath());
                return "You successfully uploaded \"test.jpg\"!";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "You failed to upload test.jpg => " + e.getMessage();
            }
        } else {
            return "You failed to upload test.jpg because the file was empty.";
        }
    }
```

How can i do this?

Comment: You should show the code that brings that message.

Comment: This message is generated by Spring when i do the request.

Answer (score 0):

May be the following code help to you to upload the image in server

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(<server api url>);
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
File myFile = new File(<file_path>);
FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(myFile);
entity.addPart("upload_param_name",fileBody);
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,
                    localContext);
HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();
xmlString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
Log.d("SOAP ", "Result : " + xmlString.toString());
```

Also for this, you have to use the .jar of **apache-mine** and **httpmine** in your apps **libs** folder.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i convert the image in base64 and send to server how a String and in my Server reconvert to image.

Thanks!